# Cannot iterate correctly through firebase realtime database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm quite new to android studio and firebase and I'm having trouble retrieving specific key value from the firebase realtime database.

So, I have an array of users in the firebase realtime database and I want to iterate through the whole array but I "move" iterator once every time I press the button "next" until the end of the array.

It is not static, that is, size of the array can change.

When I move iterator (when I press the button) I want to get "status" message from the firebase realtime database for that user (first time when I press the button next iterator will be 1 and I want to get status message for the user who's key is 1 and so on).

Sorry It wouldn't let me post an image

Link of my firebase database:

[image]

The code below works but it is always returning "status" value of the last user that has joined the array.

My code looks like this:

```
next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(current_person < number_of_people_in_the_row){
            current_person++;

            current_person.setText(String.valueOf(current_person));

            final String current_person_string = String.valueOf(current_person );

            DatabaseReference user = db.getReference("Redovi").child("Aktivni").child(pin);
            user.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for(DataSnapshot current_user: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        current_user.child(current_person_string);

                        for(DataSnapshot current_user_data: current_user.getChildren()){
                            String current_user_status = current_user_data.child("status").getValue().toString();

                            Toast.makeText(RedomatAdmin.this, current_user_status, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: What do you mean through "always returning "status" value of the last user that has joined the array."? You get a single result?

Comment: @Karlo You get a result every time you press the button or you just get the Toast message when a new user joins the array?

Comment: @AlexMamo in the picture I posted I have 5 users and everytime I click button "next" I would get toast "status" of the 5th user in the array, If I were to add 3 more users and change manually status of the 8th user in the database to "inactive" I would always get status of only that 8th user.

Comment: @P5music When I press "next" button I want to get "status" message of that user (so a single status message for that specific user), here I'm using toast just to check if I'm getting corrent values.

Comment: @Karlo If you code snippet is just a check, it seems that the Toast is issued when you manually change the value, so it is the last value. If your real code is not provided, please provide the original code or a snippet.

Comment: So you get a single Toast message, right? Or one Toast for each child?

Comment: @P5music The code in the snippet is the code that is ran when the "next" button is pressed. As you see I'm am quite inexperienced a bit over my head. But this is the only way (that I have found) to get a value from a specific key in the firebase realtime database

Comment: @Karlo but it seems that you are using an event listener that could be confusing your debug.

Comment: @AlexMamo I need to compate "status" message and check if it is active or not, but yes, one Toast for each child

Comment: @P5music Do you have any suggestions that I could try? Sorry I didn't provide all of the code as it is written in non english because it is an assignment so it's mandatory

Comment: @Karlo First you have to retrieve the next value without setting values yourself because it would fire some events. If data can be added only to the end of the array maybe you do not have to worry because you will get it after the other data has been checked by pressing the button a certain amount of time. If data can change after you checked it, your method could be not the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looping over data, and showing a toast for certain nodes in there. But since your code will execute very quickly, you'll likely only end up seeing the last toast that your code generates.

Toast messages are not great for debugging, so I highly recommend switching to `Log` calls for this purpose. In the below code I make two changes:

1. Only show a single toast message with all data, after the loops are done.
2. Log the values at every loop, so that you can find them in the logcat output.

```
DatabaseReference user = db.getReference("Redovi").child("Aktivni").child(pin);
user.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String toast = "";
        for(DataSnapshot current_user: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            String current_user_key = current_user.getKey();
            Log.d("NEXT", "Handling user "+current_user_key);
            for(DataSnapshot current_user_data: current_user.getChildren()){
                String current_user_status = current_user_data.child("status").getValue().toString();

                Log.d("NEXT", "Handling data "+current_user_data.getKey()+" status="+current_user_status);

                toast = toast + current_user_key + " = " + current_user_status + ", ";
            }
        }
        Toast.makeText(RedomatAdmin.this, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore errors please
    }
});
```

Even better is to learn to use the interactive debugger in Android Studio, set a breakpoint in your `onDataChange` and then step through the code to see what happens at a more leisurely pace. :)